# Using UnsafeMutableRawPointers with Metal buffers in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers

I've some Metal buffers which I populate with geometry data. Most data consists of `Float`s, but the buffer also contains custom structs for the tessellation stage.
I get the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` for the Metal buffer in this way:

`let origin=geometryBuffer.contents()`

Which I then supply to the following function:

```
    func populate(bufferPointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, useTessellation: Bool) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        var bufferPointer = bufferPointer

        if let vertexData = vertexData {
            var floatPointer = bufferPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)

            for index in vertexData.indexes {
                floatPointer[0]=vertexData.vertices[Int(3*index+0)]
                floatPointer[1]=vertexData.vertices[Int(3*index+1)]
                floatPointer[2]=vertexData.vertices[Int(3*index+2)]

                floatPointer=floatPointer.advanced(by: 3)
            }

            bufferPointer = floatPointer.deinitialize(count: 0)
        } else if useTessellation, let patchData=patchData {
            memcpy(bufferPointer, patchData, patchData.count*MemoryLayout<PatchIn>.stride)
            bufferPointer=bufferPointer.advanced(by: patchData.count*MemoryLayout<PatchIn>.stride)
        }

        if let lineData = lineVertexData {
            var floatPointer = bufferPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)

            floatPointer[0]=lineData[0].x
            floatPointer[1]=lineData[0].y
            floatPointer[2]=0
            floatPointer[3]=lineData[1].x
            floatPointer[4]=lineData[1].y
            floatPointer[5]=0

            floatPointer=floatPointer.advanced(by: 6)
            bufferPointer = floatPointer.deinitialize(count: 0)
        }

        return bufferPointer
    }
```

I'm very uncertain here about my usage of `assumingMemoryBound(to:)`, `deinitialize(count:)` and the `memcpy()`.

The code seems to run fine, but according to the documentation it's quite easy to get into undefined behaviour. So I wonder whether I'm using the pointers correctly.

Thanks in advance.